# RavenDb Map index querying confusion

Tags: .net, ravendb

Let's assume we have the following Map index:

```
public class CommentsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post>
{
   public class IndexResult
   {
      public string PostId {get;set;}
      public DateTime CommentDateTime {get;set;}
   }

   public CommentsIndex()
   {
       Map = posts => from post in posts
                      from comment in post.Comment
                      select new { PostId = post.Id, CommentDateTime = comment.DateTime }; 
   }
}
```

The result of this index query will be a collection of Post documents. But how can I query it by `CommentDateTime`? Following query will definitely not work as `CommentDateTime` is not part of `Post` document:

```
_documentSession.Query<Post, CommentsIndex>().Where(x => x.CommentDateTime < DateTime.UtcNow).ToList();
```

P. S. I know I can use live projection or calling `AsProjection` to shape the index query result, but I guess there should be a more natural solution for such a simple case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_documentSession.Query<CommentsIndex.IndexResult, CommentsIndex>()
    .Where(x => x.CommentDateTime < DateTime.UtcNow)
    .As<Post>()
    .ToList();
```

Note: there is a fundamental difference between `.As<T>()` and `.AsProjection<T>()`, as only the latter will try to get the fields and the first only *casts* the results.

Comment: Does it actually work? I am trying to get the same behavior with last Raven build and cannot do it.

Comment: Alexander, a lot of things have changed since then. I suggest you post a complete description to the mailing list.